# excel cell locations based on value in another cell

Tags: excel-formula

I am using Excel 2010. I would like to be able to use the value of a cell (such as the value in cell A1) in a function that will define the location to get data from another spreadsheet.

='Sheet1'!$B$xx (where the value of xx is defined in cell A1)

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with Indirect(). Note that Indirect() is volatile and using it much can slow down large workbooks.

```
=Indirect("Sheet1!$B$"&A1)
```

Another (non-volatile) option is to use Index, like this

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet2!A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That was what I was looking for.

Comment: Please accept the post that solved your problem as the answer, as described in the [Tour]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Index, preferable to use INDEX as it is less volatile.

```
=INDEX(B:B,A1)
```

This returns a value or the reference to a value from within a table or range

Comment: Thank you. That was just what I needed.